# Why does the and operator does not work in this sql code

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT stadt.Name, stadt.Nummer, stadt.Gebiet
FROM stadt
LEFT JOIN land ON land.Hauptstadtnummer = stadt.Nummer
WHERE land.Hauptstadtnummer IS NULL
AND land.Kontinent = "Europe"
ORDER BY stadt.Einwohner DESC;
```

Does anyone knows why the two *where* conditions dont work together and I only get a blank table, while when I am using only one condition of them it works perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

Because, after the join, there are no rows where both conditions are true at the same time.

Your where clause does not work as `rows where X is true, and also the rows where Y is true`

Rather, it works as `rows where (both 'X is true' and 'Y is true')`

You almost certainly need `OR`...

```
WHERE
    land.Hauptstadtnummer IS NULL
 OR land.Kontinent = 'Europe'
```

This will give rows where there at least one of the conditions is true...

- There wasn't a match found in the `land` table during the `LEFT JOIN`
- OR
- There was a match found in the land table, and that continent is Europe

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure given that no input was provided, but you're using `land.Hauptstadnummer` as join condition and then filtering where the join key is null AND another attribute or the left table(land.Kontinent) is equal to `Europe`.

Assuming that `land.Kontinent` can't be null, if the `land.Hauptstadnummer` is null then no entry in the left table was found and hence `land.Kontinent = Europe` never happens.

And if `land.Kontinent = Europe` then there has to be the Hauptstadtnummer.
You can change it to an OR condition, but it relies on what you need to fetch from the data

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is simple:  the independent queries return results, but the results are on *different* rows of `land`.

What you want is aggregation, with the filtering in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Nummer, s.Gebiet
FROM stadt s LEFT JOIN
     land l
     ON l.Hauptstadtnummer = s.Nummer
GROUP BY s.Name, s.Nummer, s.Gebiet
HAVING SUM(l.Hauptstadtnummer IS NULL) > 0 AND
       SUM(land.Kontinent = 'Europe') > 0
ORDER BY MIN(s.Einwohner) DESC;
```